# Make sure html elements are closed when showing a substring on a webpage (ruby on rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I am doing this:

`entries.each do |entry|
  entry[0,1000] + "..."
end`

Let's say that entry has a <ul> and a <li> that were not closed, because it chopped the entry in the middle of a list. How can I make sure to close those tags out, so rendering isn't messed up?

I was considering creating a method that found the last index of <ul> and made sure it was less than the last index of </ul>, etc. This seems cumbersome though. Any ideas on how to solve this with ruby on rails?

Thanks!

Comment: What are those entries and why do they contain markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [hpricot](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot) gem:

```
Hpricot("<ul><li>foo<ul><li>bar").to_html
=> "<ul><li>foo<ul><li>bar</li></ul></li></ul>"
```